# Block automatic unroll of XML child nodes with single child node and where NodeType = element

Tags: xml, powershell

I have a need to take an XML element as an optional argument are process conditionally depending on if that `<Rules>` element has child `<Rule>` elements or not, and also if nothing is passed. I am loading the XML from file with comments.
So, given this XML

```
$xml = [Xml]@"
<Root>
    <Rules>
        <Rule>
            <Property>set</Property> 
            <Operator>-eq</Operator>
            <Value>Task_Move_Ex</Value>
        </Rule>
        <Rule>
            <Property>set</Property> 
            <Operator>-eq</Operator>
            <Value>Task_Move_Ex</Value>
        </Rule>
        <!-- -->
    </Rules>
</Root>
"@
```

I can `SelectSingleNode` to get the `<Rules>` element and then get a count of child Element items this way

```
$rules = $xml.SelectSingleNode('//Rules')
($rules.ChildNodes | where {$_.NodeType -eq 'Element'}).Count
```

This works with two child `<Rule>` elements, and if I assign `$rules.ChildNodes | where {$_.NodeType -eq 'Element'}` to a variable, the type of that variable will be `[System.Object]`. However, if there is only one `<Rule>` the type will be `[System.Xml.XmlElement]` and there will be no count. I *THINK* this might be similar to PowerShell's automatic unroll of single element arrays, but not sure what the appropriate version of the `@()` array wrapper is. I could go the long way round and respond to a type of `[System.Xml.XmlElement]` or a count `-gt` 1, but I want to also loop through the resulting collection and send each `<Rule>` to be processed by another function. So I would rather have a collection that supports counts of 1 and 1+.

Comment: You can just wrap your statement in an array. 
`@($rules.ChildNodes | where { $_.NodeType -eq 'Element' })`

1 result will be wrapped in a array. 
Multiple results will automatically get unrolled from the first array to their array (so you won't end up with a double array)

Comment: Why not just query for the `<Rule>` elements directly? `$xml.SelectNodes('//Rules/Rule').Count`

Comment: Or something like `$xml.SelectNodes('//Rules//Element').Count`. You've unfortunately anonymized away all context of the actual problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @mathias-r-jessen I am hoping for a generic solution, as in other situations I might need more granular control. Was hoping for a simple way to get all non comments, but perhaps no way to do that.

Comment: @bacon-bits If I am understanding right, this won't work because the NAME of my element isn't element, I need to get all Elements and filter all comments. As for anonymizing things away, it seems I rarely strike the right balance. Too often I have posed a question and gotten shot down because it isn't the ABOLUTE MINIMUM functional code. This time I went too far the other way, and lost the context. But generally speaking, for an element that perhaps contains other elements, comments and even text, I want to just get all the child elements.

Comment: @sage-pourpre So, I basically end up with an array of elements, with one or more elements possible? Can it be so simple? :) Will try that in a bit!

Comment: So, it looks like @sage-pourpre has the solution I need; it's generic, it lets me iterate over the resulting collection and send individual rules for processing as `[XmlElement]`s.